# React Async Select how to create dynamically

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, fetch, react-select

Would be possible with React Select Async to pass the source dynamically and consume data on the flow?

```
let fields = this.state.fields.map((field, i) => { 
        <div key={i} className={"field-wrapper"}>
            <AsyncSelect
               cacheOptions
               //loadOptions={loadOptions} this should fetsch direcl from field.source (url)
               //defaultOptions
               placeholder={field.label}
               onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
            />
        </div>
});
```

and here is what I tried

```
<AsyncSelect
      loadOptions= { 
         function (inputValue, callback) {
           Requests.get(field.source, (status, data) => {
                 callback(data);
           });
       }}
       isDisabled={disabled}
       defaultOptions
       placeholder={field.label}
       onInputChange={this.handleSelectChange}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage separate fields with giving uniq `key` on the flow. Because if you don't do it second field don't know when first field changes value. And if you give uniq changeable key second can load from remote data which depends from first field. React doesnt know where your fields should re-render and get another `source` on the flow. And that for it you should manage uniq `key` of field for changing source and get new data from remote. For example you can connect it with another `field` value. like:

```
key={!!values.first && !!values.first.id ? values.first.id : null}
```

And react will know that `key` changed. And re-render this field. And field gets new source on the flow.

Comment: Hi @aturan23 please can you give an example (snippet)?